# Parameterized test doesn't work in parallel execution

Tags: java, gradle, junit5, parallel-testing, parameterized-unit-test

I try to run my tests with jUnit5 annotation @ParametrizedTest in parallel execution, but it's not work.

```
public class Simple {

@Inject
private WebSteps WebSteps;

@Inject
private DbSteps dbSteps;

private void func(String string) {
    final Phone phone = Phone.of(string);

    WebSteps.openLoginPage()
            .sendCodeForPhone(phone)
            .checkCode(dbSteps.getAuthCode(phone));
}

@ParameterizedTest
@ValueSource(strings = {"9025617555", "9367173268", "9725000875"})
@Ui
@Execution(CONCURRENT)
public void test(String phone) {
    func(phone);
}}
```

Only one of three tests run normal.

I use Gradle, jUnit 5.6.0, Atlas as Selenium Wrapper (UI)

Comment: Can you describe how it's not working?

Comment: If that's a browser test, you probablt only have a single browser under test, so they will conflict if they are run in parallel

Comment: @tim_yates, yes, i am testing browser, but you know in test starting all browsers opened, but worked only one